# Get UITablieViewCell's indexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

How can I get the cell's indexpath after I have created the cell? I need to set a uniq cell.tag. Any other idea how I can do that?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject
{
    ConditionCell *cell = (ConditionCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[ConditionCell reuseIdentifier]];

    if ( nil == cell )
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ConditionCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    } else
    {
        // Reset Image
        cell.img.image = nil;
    }
```

The reason is I need to find the cell in a different thred

```
[condition processImageDataWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData) {
            if (self.view.window) {
                if (cell.tag == [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@",cell.tag);
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    [condition writeToFile:imageData];
                    if (image)
                    {
                        cell.img.image = image;
                        [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                    }
                    [condition release];
                }
            }
        }];
```

Comment: doesnt this answer your own question - [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]?

Comment: It would. BUT it does not work. It always returns nil.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is your calling it not on the main thread because it is a UIView - try this:

```
- (void)someMethodToStartAsync
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = however your getting your cell;
    NSAssert(cell, @"cell was nil");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    [condition processImageDataWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData) {
        // do something with indexPath
    }
}
```

indexPath will be a copy when used in the block, so if you want the value you initialized to be reflected outside of the block declare it like so:

```
_block NSIndexPath *indexPath = whatever;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have found another solution. As the content of each cell is unique i use this as the tag. The problem was that the table has not been drawn at that point. So it could not know the indexpath by then.

Comment: @Chris I was just guessing :-x